# SerialPort not taking input. It throws it back at me!

Tags: c#, sms, serial-port, gsm

When I try to write an AT command to my GSM modem, it does not seem to take the command.  I have used PuTTY to check that the command words, it does.  I have checked to see if the port is opening, it does.

What could I possibly be doing wrong?

NOTE:  The "lol" part is for debugging purposes.  ;3

```
SerialPort sp = new SerialPort("COM3");
sp.BaudRate = 9600;
sp.DataBits = 8;
sp.StopBits = StopBits.One;
sp.Parity = Parity.None;
sp.Open();
if (sp.IsOpen == false)
{
    sp.Open();
}
Thread.Sleep(1000);
sp.WriteLine("AT+CMGF=1");
Thread.Sleep(1000);
string lol = sp.ReadExisting();
sp.Close();
return lol;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throws it back? an `ATE0` will disable it echoing what you send it.

You should probably also issue an `ATQ0` to tell the device you want responses, otherwise it won't issue `OK`s. (a subsequent `ATV1` will make them verbose) also issue a `AT+CMEE=1` to activate error responses.

There are also [existing libraries](http://www.scampers.org/steve/sms/index.htm) that are designed to work with GSM Modems that will save you the trouble, if you want to do it yourself a [port monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644.aspx) will save you pulling out your hair by showing you exactly what being sent/received.

Answer (score 1):

Some things to verify...

Is the [NewLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.newline.aspx) property correct for your modem?  The default is a line feed.

How about the [RtsEnable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.rtsenable.aspx) and [DtrEnable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.dtrenable.aspx) values?

Is the [Handshake](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.handshake.aspx) property correct?